# Несколько запросов к MongoDB и отправка полученных данных на сайт. Node.js

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, mongodb

Недавно начал работать с Js, Node и появилась необходимость в Mongodb.

В чём проблема:

Сайт посылает на сервер запрос, после чего сервер обращается к базе данных и отсылает полученные данные на рендер. Однако я не понимаю, как отправить эти данные одним запросом.

Пример.
Допустим, есть две коллекции:

Первая:

```
{
  type: 'video',
  title: 'видосик'
}
{
  type: 'photo',
  title: 'фоточка'
}
```

Вторая:

```
{
  nickname: 'dodik',
  name: 'oleg'
}
```

Что нужно сделать:

```
app.get('страничка', (request, response) => {

  **Первые**   = {полученные данные из первой коллекции},
  **Вторые**   = {полученные данные из второй коллекции};

  response.render('страничка', {types: **Первые**, peoples: **Вторые**});
};
```

Есть мысль, что нужно объявить два массива, а потом положить в них данные, полученные двумя запросами к бд, вроде этого:

```
app.get('страничка', (request, response) => {

  var dbtypes   = {},
      dbpeoples = {};

  function first(){
  **Подключение к базе данных**
    **Подключение к первой коллекции**
      **Получение данных**
        **Внесение полученных данных в dbtypes**
  }

  function second(){
  **Подключение к базе данных**
    **Подключение ко второй коллекции**
      **Получение данных**
        **Внесение полученных данных в dbpeoples**
  }

  function final(){
    first();

    Затем, если все данные внеслись в массив, запустить:

    second();

    И потом, если и вторые данные внесены, отправить:

    response.render('страничка', {types: dbtypes, peoples: dbpeoples});
  };
};
```

Но всё уходит в ступор из-за синхронности и из-за данных, возвращаемых методом find - не могу понять, как  проверить, внеслись ли они целиком в массив или ещё нет, что бы потом запустить вторую функцию. Ломаю голову уже 4-й день...

Comment: конечно нужно управлять потоком запросов, вот пример async:  http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для пакетного выполнения запросов можно использовать `Promise.all([...])`, для управления асинхронным потоком `async/await` или библиотеки, например [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/), к примеру [waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall)